# How to get names of top 2 countries(based on how many times they appear in the table) using expressions in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I am currently using a hardcoded solution but would prefer a dynamic expression.

```
=Lookup("USA", Fields!Country.Value, Fields!count_unique_company.Value, "InvCountry") &; " of the top 15 investors are based in the United States and " &; Lookup("Spain", Fields!country.Value, Fields!count_unique_company.Value, "InvCountry") &; " are based in Spain"
```

| Name of Company | Sales | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 12 | Spain |
| ccc | 11 | Spain |
| asv | 14 | Spain |
| efd | 15 | USA |
| cgd | 12 | Spain |
| uhs | 18 | USA |
| vjs | 14 | USA |
| chs | 16 | Germany |
| laj | 17 | Germany |
| old | 10 | Germany |
| afc | 1 | USA |
| a a c | 2 | USA |
| werc | 122 | USA |

Comment: While there is a `RowNumber` function in SSRS to do this type of operation, this is much better handled in the SQL as Tim described.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses aggregation along with `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Country, COUNT(*), DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Country
)

SELECT Country
FROM cte
WHERE rnk <= 2;
```

Note that there may be a potential edge case requiring clarification, should there be ties for the first or second positions.  The above query will return more than 2 countries in the event that there be ties for the first or seconds positions.